# change class when click in angular 8

Tags: angular

I am not able to change class when clicking on the button.

I am using this.

```
event.srcElement.classList.remove("unsubscribe");
event.srcElement.classList.add("subscribe");
```

I am passing the event in function when clicking on the button.

```
<a #subscribe title="unsubscribe" *ngIf="rec?.attributes?.Subscription == 'true'" class='unsubscribe'  (click)="subscribeUnsubscribe($event);$event.stopPropagation();" data-toggle="modal"></a>
<a #subscribe title="subscribe" *ngIf="rec?.attributes?.Subscription == 'false' || rec?.attributes?.Subscription == null || rec?.attributes?.Subscription == 'undefined'" class='subscribe'  (click)="subscribeUnsubscribe($event);$event.stopPropagation();" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

The problem is I am having two angular components in one component the srcElement is working fine and toggling the classes, but in another component, it is not working and giving the below error.

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'srcElement' of undefined
```

Comment: Can't you use [ngClass] for it?

Comment: @SunnyParekh, no I want to achieve this with srcElement it is working in another component

Comment: is it in your directive.ts file?

Comment: @JayeshVyas There is no real reason to use the classList. You have such an amazing framework and you use plain javascript dom?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the reason why it gives you an error, but this code is not enough to know really. Have you considered using the `NgClass` directive? [Here a tutorial](https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/)

You can do something like this:

Component:

```js
public subscribed: boolean;
```

Template:

```html
<div #someElement [class.subscribe]="!subscribed" [class.unsubscribe]="subscribed"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you can do something like this:

```
subscribeUnsubscribe(event) {
 event.srcElement.classList.remove("unsubscribe");
    setTimeout(()=>{
      event.srcElement.classList.add("subscribe");
    },0)
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Have you used timeout?

Comment: Can you create a sample on stackblitz to help us understand your concern?

Answer (score 0):

Use ngClass to check all your conditions and return your style class. For example:

```
<a #subscribe [ngClass]="getstyleClass(rec)" title="unsubscribe" (click)="subscribeUnsubscribe($event);$event.stopPropagation();" data-toggle="modal"></a>
```

and in your component file

```
public getstyleClass(rec: any):string {
 if (rec?.attributes?.Subscription === true){
  return "unsubscribe";
 }
 if (rec?.attributes?.Subscription == 'false' || rec?.attributes?.Subscription == null || rec?.attributes?.Subscription == 'undefined') {
  return "subscribe"; 
 }
 return "";
}
```